# SD card don't fit to card slot fully

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, sd-card, dell-inspiron

Dell Inspiron 15 3000 series laptop, when I tried insert SD card in slot, it looks that SD card can't be physically inserted into the slot fully: it can be inserted only in half. Although SD card is properly recognized and displayed.

[image]

What can be the problem here?

Comment: If it's properly recognized and displayed, why do you think there's a problem?

Answer (score 5):

Just looks to me like they're saving money & space.

Not all SD card slots are full-depth with spring mechanism, many are as simple as yours. I have computers with each type.